# Probability of getting die roll match (e.g roll a $5$ on roll $5$) at least once on an $n$-dimensional die in $n$ rolls as $n$ approaches infinity

Tags: probability, limits, dice

The title pretty much says it all.

If you have some *n*-dimensional die, and you roll the die n times, what is the probability you'll get at least one "roll match" - that you roll the number *i* on the *i*th roll?

My reasoning was:

$$\begin{align*}
\text{ since } 1 - P(\text{no roll matches at all}) &= P(\text{ at least one match})\\[5pt] 
&= 1 - \left (\frac{(n-1)}{n} \right) ^n\\
\end{align*}$$

And then we take the limit as n approaches infinity

$$\begin{align*}
&\lim_{n \to \infty} 1 - \left (\frac{(n-1)}{n} \right) ^n\\[5pt] 
&=\lim_{n \to \infty} 1 - \left (\frac{(\infty-1)}{\infty} \right) ^n\\[5pt]
&=\lim_{n \to \infty} 1 -(1) ^\infty\\[5pt]
&=\lim_{n \to \infty} 1 -(1)\\[5pt]
&= 0\\[5pt]
\end{align*}$$

And this kind of makes sense to me? It feels like as although we roll the die more, even though we're rolling it a very large amount of times, the probability of actually getting the right side approaches $0$.

But the answer on Slader (for my textbook) says this:

> **(b)**
>
> If we are dealing with an $n$-sided die then we have $P(C_i)=1/n$. Hence we compute
>
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty} P(C_1 \cup \dots \cup C_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \bigg(1-\bigg(1-\frac{1}{n}\bigg)^n\bigg)=1-\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(1-\frac{1}{n}\bigg)^n,$$
>
> where we note that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-1/n)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{-1}{n})^n$ is a famous limit from calculus/analysis, equalling the number $e^{-1}$ where $e \approx 2.718$. Thus our result is
>
> $$1-e^{-1}\approx 0.632.$$

I would be grateful if someone could help me out!
Thanks

Comment: $1^\infty$ is an indeterminate form, you cannot say it equals $1$ (or anything else) without additional justification. Plus, this limit is the definition of $e$

Comment: Were you actually using your feeling that the answer should be $0$ to guide your calculations? That's dangerous—I recommend, when first dealing with complicated limits, that you use the calculations to shape your feelings, not the other way around.

Comment: @GregMartin I wasn't! I think I just calculated it and then figured that the matching intuition made sense afterwards.

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with "dimensional."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your last calculation, you seem to be using a "rule" that if $\lim_{n\to\infty} B(n) = 1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} E(n) = \infty$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} B(n)^{E(n)} = 1$. This is an incorrect rule (and this example actually shows why).

This is actually an example of the "$1^\infty$ indeterminate form", which is called an indeterminate form precisely because knowing the limits of $B(n)$ and $E(n)$ is not enough information to determine the limit of $B(n)^{E^(n)}$. (This is in contrast to say $\lim_{n\to\infty} B(n) = 2$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} E(n) = 5$ implying $\lim_{n\to\infty} B(n)^{E(n)} = 2^5$, where the individual limits are sufficient information to determine the complicated limit.) Indeterminate forms are a significant topic when studying limits, and various tools exist (such as l'Hôpital's rule) for figuring out their values.

By the way, the previous line of the calculation also invoked a false "rule", namely that if $\lim_{n\to\infty} N(n) = \infty$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} D(n) = \infty$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{N(n)}{D(n)} = 1$. This is another indeterminate form, the $\frac\infty\infty$ indeterminate form, and the example $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2n-1}n$ shows that the answer is not always $1$. The OP happened to get the right answer here, but that was just good luck, not a valid step.

Comment: Thanks! I totally forgot $-1^\infty$ was indeterminate because I think I misread it as $1^\infty$, which would actually = 1. Also, I didn't mean to make it look like i used the false rule which you mentioned on the previous line of calculations - I think I didn't really show that properly, but I know that doesn't always work - for example, the answer to your example is 2, not 1.

Comment: @DownstairsPanda No, $1^\infty$ is an [indeterminate form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form). You can't just say that it "would actually = 1". With such forms, you need to examine the limit process leading to the form to see if the limit actually exists, and if so, to determine its numerical value. FWIW, for all finite $x$, $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{n+x}{n}\right)^n=e^x$$